# slow environment with high CPU usage

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sysadmin, mysqldump

I'm new to Linux metrics

in our test environment we experiment a slowness, after investigation we have found that the disk space used to store backup data is full, but what is wired for me is that the disk i/o is not high at all

we are working with MySQL server

here is the output of the top command[image]

Comment: if the disk is full its like driving uphill with handbrake, however this screenshot does tell nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, what you need to know if this screenshots Do not say anything for you ?

Comment: Find the slow query, show it to us, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  From there, we can drive downhill.

Comment: at first show us ` df -h ` and also the load level as also the output of lscpu for one cpu moreover how big is the db?

Comment: i check the log file for slow query, but there is nothing there, i'm sure this is about no more enough space in the disk partition of backups, because when i deleted old backups the CPU return to its normal state, my question is why the disk i/o is not high considering that the problem is from the disk partition of backups